# SharePoint 2013 Business Data Connectivity - Adding Columns

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I've created an external content type in SharePoint Designer which points to a view in a database. In my User Profile Service Application, I create a new Synchronization Connection that points to this ECT so I can map use properties to columns in my view.

If I add a new column to my view and refresh the ECT in SharePoint Designer, the new column doesn't appear when I try to map an attribute to this column. I need to delete the Synchronization Connection and re-create it. Unfortunately when I do this, all my user property mappings are lost and I need to re-map them all again.

Is there a way to refresh the Synchronization Connection such that it recognises the new column I've added? I've also tried refreshing the associated Management Agent in Forefront Identity Manager but this didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Only because you didn't mention it: Have you tried running a full synch?

Comment: Yep, I've tried running a full synch to no avail.